# When the app opens up it has to be clicked once for it to start registering onclicklisteners and every click basically

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a game and I have used 2 FrameLayouts to switch them on and off. When I start up the app through my Smasung phone in order for it to register any clicks on the start button I have to click somewhere on the screen first. However, when I open it through the emulator it works as intended and the start button will be clicked off the bat.
This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framePlaying"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearTimer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearCounter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="34sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="60dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorOnPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearStartUI"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round"
                        android:focusable="auto"
                        android:text="@string/key_btnStart"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvWelcome"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvWelcome"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvWelcome" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvWelcome"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/key_tvWelcome"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
setRequestedVisible: visible=true, type=1, host=com.matesucic.reflextapper/com.matesucic.reflextapper.MainActivity, 
from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.show:229 android.view.InsetsController.showDirectly:1437 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1110 

android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417 android.view.InsetsController.show:962 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6146 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8653 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 
2022-11-14 23:17:08.041 29280-29280 ViewRootIm...nActivity]     D  controlInsetsForCompatibility: hideByFlags=0x0, showByFlags=0x2, flags=0x81810100, sysUiVis=0x0, matchParent=true, nonAttachedAppWindow=true

2022-11-14 23:17:08.053 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376611228917184]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.053 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376611228917184]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.056 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xdc164a7 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 

android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 

android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 

android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 

android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 

android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376611228818976]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376611228818976]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376611228828656]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376611228828656]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376611228817568]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376611228817568]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.059 29280-29280 ViewRootIm...nActivity]  I  Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=15 res=0x1 s={true -5476376606934137680} ch=false fn=3

2022-11-14 23:17:08.306 29280-29595 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376611228963120]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.306 29280-29595 SurfaceControl  I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376611228963120]

2022-11-14 23:17:08.371 19651-19910 SemIWCMonitor.File      pid-19651   E  DYNAMIC-QAI: : Foreground package - com.matesucic.reflextapper
```

That is the output on the first click when it "focuses" on the app.

I tried changing the focus attributes of the framelayouts and also put

```
frameStart.requestFocus();
```

into the java code. But nothing changed.

Comment: You need to add the code, otherwise nobody knows what you are doing. A general hint: You are nesting many ViewGroups (LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout etc.). This is very bad for performance. Try to use only one ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Alright, I will try to make new activities as the many layouts might be causing the problem. Also the code in Java doesn't really relate with the problem but if the problem persists after adding new activities I will add the code to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was a problem in Java code.
For some reason when I hide the navigation bar in the onCreate method with the code line: `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` I have to double tap on my actual phone to focus onto the window but not in the simulator. Sorry I didn't upload the Java code as I didn't suspect it had to do anything with it. Thanks anyways!